# Target specific toastr element

Tags: toastr

Using [toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) to have my FCM popups come up on the screen. The notifications are of different kinds (success, info etc) - how would I target the specific element that I am currently firing?

This is my code:

```
// Handle incoming messages
messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
  console.log("Notification received: ", payload);
  toastr["success"](payload.notification.body, payload.notification.title, {
      "closeButton": true,
      "debug": false,
      "newestOnTop": false,
      "progressBar": true,
      "positionClass": "toast-top-left",
      "preventDuplicates": false,
      "showDuration": 30000,
      "hideDuration": 1000,
      "timeOut": 0,
      "extendedTimeOut": 0,
      "showEasing": "swing",
      "hideEasing": "linear",
      "showMethod": "fadeIn",
      "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
       });  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Am I right in thinking you want to get the last toast generated?

If the toast still exists in the DOM then this will get the most recent generated toast that is still on screen

```
$('.toast').last();
```